# Sqlite table creation

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to create tables based on a columns data?

I currently have a table named `Exchange` which contains numerous columns

```
ID:NAME:PRICE
1:Stick:12
2:Stone:20
3:Water:1
4:Water:1
```

But I want to create numerous tables based on the `Name` column and select the rows that contain that name and move them to their respective table.

So in the above example, the result would be 3 new tables

`Stick`, `Stone` & `Water`

The table `Water` would be

```
1:Water:1
2:Water:1
```

Comment: Don't do it. But if you really must head down this route have you considered views instead of tables?

Comment: This is really an SQL issue and nothing to do with UNIX&Linux

Answer (score 1):

Do not do it. It is extremely bad idea to create numerous tables.

Better learn EAV model (which is already in use in your `Exchange` table):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model